# Access API using client id and secret key in laravel/lumen

Tags: web-services, api, laravel, jwt, lumen

I have created an API for my web application. Now I want to give access to the world but before giving access I want mechanism something like Facebook API, Twitter API, Google API who provides client ID and Secret Key. Currently, I am using JWT AuthController, user login with his credentials and return a token, I don't want the users to be login.

I want the user can access my API using client ID and secret key? Another thing is that and How I will create client ID's and secret keys for the users?

Is this can be achieved using JWT Auth?

Any help?

Comment: any api developer here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read the article and quite promising it is, but after few post it recommends to use oauth2, here you go:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/api-authorization-via-public-and-secret-keys

quotes:

> Just add in the class to your API config.
>
> ```
> namespace App\Providers\Guard;
>
> use Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\Authorization; use
> Dingo\Api\Routing\Route; use Illuminate\Http\Request; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
>
> class GuardProvider extends Authorization {
>     /**
>       * Get the providers authorization method.
>       *
>       * @return string
>       */
>      public function getAuthorizationMethod()
>      {
>          return 'X-Authorization';
>      }
>
>      /**
>       * Authenticate the request and return the authenticated user instance.
>       *
>       * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
>       * @param \Dingo\Api\Routing\Route $route
>       *
>       * @return mixed
>       */
>      public function authenticate(Request $request, Route $route)
>      {
>          $key = $request->header(env('API_AUTH_HEADER', 'X-Authorization'));
>          if (empty($key)) $key = $request->input(env('API_AUTH_HEADER', 'X-Authorization'));
>          if (empty($key)) throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Guard', 'The supplied API KEY is missing or an invalid authorization header was sent');
>
>          $user = app('db')->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.key = ?", [$key]);
>          if (!$user) throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Guard', 'The supplied API KEY is not valid');
>
>          return $user;
>      } 
> }
> ```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: very bad behavior but on top of it bad behavior that I got frequent 2 downvoted (not willing to give me chance), I am here to help as you can see but today is very bad day